# Prevent Emacs from messaging when it writes recentf

Tags: minibuffer, message, recentf, timers

I've configured Emacs to save recentf every five minutes by using this code:

```elisp
(run-at-time nil (* 5 60) 'recentf-save-list)
```

It works great, but after writing recentf Emacs feels it has to tell me about it, so every 5 minutes I get a message in the minibuffer telling me it wrote recentf.

How do I silence that message?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One solution for that narrow case is to dynamically set `save-silently` for that invocation specific invocation.  Try:

```
(run-at-time nil (* 5 60)
             (lambda ()
               (let ((save-silently t))
                 (recentf-save-list))))
```

You might alternatively use advice to globally accomplish the same thing.  See [Advising Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html) in the Emacs Lisp Manual.

Comment: I had to also add `(inhibit-message t) to the let bindings as per https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-emacs/2016-08/msg00364.html